# No Authorisation REST API after Publish Header

Tags: powerbi

I have designed a dashboard within Power BI Desktop using our own data. This data is accessed using a REST API which is authorized using a token in the header. Everything works fine, but then I publish to Power BI Services and want to schedule the refresh. It shows a 400 error. Is it possible that that the header is lost during publishing?

[Screenshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ufAf.png)

I checked for hours on forums, but couldn't find any real solution. The only thing I found was this topic but without any solution. Can someone help me to fix this final piece?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the inline definition of headers in the `Web.Contents` method.

So instead of this:

```
  Source = Web.Contents(
    "https://api.tld",
        [Headers=[#"Authorization"="Bearer <your_personal_token_here>"  ]   ]
    )
```

Use this:

```
    vUrl = "https://api.tld",
    vHeaders =[
            #"Authorization"="Bearer <your_personal_token_here>"
        ],
    Source = Web.Contents(vUrl, [Headers=vHeaders])
```

See my Gist for [Loading GraphQL data (GitHub API v4) into PowerBI](https://gist.github.com/petrsvihlik/cc34a6cf1882d515139c5b27f37cf99e/revisions#diff-81057a395f17b0b4d473a75da11e442c) which I just recently updated with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I tested rocky's suggestion but I got stuck at the same authentication point mentioned by Menno Veen... in Service Power BI settings.

For PowerQuery code, I used this one (a bit simpler than rocky's) and also worked.

Note: I got stuck at the same point in Power BI Service.

```
let
source = Web.Contents(
"https://api.url",
[
    Headers=[
        #"Method"="POST",
        #"Content-Type"="application/json",
        #"Authorization"="Bearer <your_personal_token_here>"
    ],
    Content=Text.ToBinary("{""query"": ""{   organization(login: \""github\"") { name  }}""}"),

#"JSON" = Json.Document(source)
in
JSON
```